# How to find distance between two set of co-ordinates in php

Tags: php

Let suppose i have two set of co-ordinates, i got these co-ordinates from map source through android application and sent it to server, now server side will calculate distance between them and print.

Comment: can you share some of codes

Comment: no sorry i haven't any code i want to initiate now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
<?php

$points = array
(
    "point1" => "0,55" ,
    "point2" => "0,52" 
);

function get_distance($inputs)
{
    $count = 1;
    foreach($inputs as $x => $y)
    {
        echo $x." = (".$y.")<br>";
        $p[$count] = explode(",",$y);
        $count++;
    }

    $x1 = $p[1][0];
    $y1 = $p[1][1];

    $x2 = $p[2][0];
    $y2 = $p[2][1];

    $distance = sqrt(pow(($x2 - $x1) , 2) + pow(($y2 - $y1) , 2));
    echo $distance;
}

get_distance($points);

?>
```

Comment: i have tried it with low points i-e "point1" => "0,5" , "point2" => "0,15". And it worked fine thanks

Comment: it gave me output 10 which was my required answer thanks again

Comment: wouldn't it be easier if you include the distance calculation within the function `get_points` rather than seperately splitting the coordinate and calculating the distance?

Comment: I suggest to change it the folllowing way:

    `<?php
    
    $points = array
    (
     "point1" => "22,55" ,
     "point2" => "55,12" 
    );
    
    function get_distance($inputs)
    {
     $count = 1;
     foreach($inputs as $x => $y)
     {
      echo $x." = (".$y.")<br>";
      $p[$count] = explode(",",$y);
      $count++;
     }
     $distance = sqrt(pow(($p[2][0] - $p[1][0]) , 2) + pow(($p[2][1] - $p[1][1]) , 2));

        return $distance;
    }
    
    $distance = get_distance($points);
    echo $distance;
    ?>`. (Of course after reformatting :))

Comment: Good suggestion, I have edited my answer. Thanks @TobiasF.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function calculateDistance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {

    $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
    $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    $unit = strtoupper($unit);

    if ($unit == "K") {
        return ($miles * 1.609344);
    } else if ($unit == "N") {
        return ($miles * 0.8684);
    } else {
        return $miles;
    }
}
```

and you can call it like:

```
calculateDistance($latitude1, $longitude1, $latitude2, $longitude2, "K");
```

[Reference](http://www.geodatasource.com/developers/php)